# Observing repository LiveData from ViewModel and notify UI

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin, android-architecture-components

Google says that is not possible to observe a LiveData from a ViewModel:

> [...] However ViewModel objects must never observe changes to
>   lifecycle-aware observables, such as LiveData objects.[...]

And I would handle the `repo.login()` result in the ViewModel and notify the UI thought the two [SingleLiveEvent](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/SingleLiveEvent.java)s, is it possible?

```
class Repository {
    // .... //
    fun login(user:String, password:String): LiveData<Status> { /* ... */ }
}

class LoginViewModel : ViewModel() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var repo: Repository

    private var auth = MutableLiveData<User>()
    private var showErrorEvent = SingleLiveEvent<String>()
    private var showSuccessEvent = SingleLiveEvent<String>()

    // Called from UI
    fun performLogin(user:User){
        repo.login(user.name, user.password)
        // We can't observe the result here 
        // and update error/success events
    }

    // Called from UI
    fun getErrorEvent() = showErrorEvent

    // Called from UI
    fun getSuccessEvent() = showSuccessEvent

}
```

Comment: Option 1: Wrap state and data in a class and expose it: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/guide.html#addendum

Comment: @JemshitIskenderov, is not an answer for this problem. I imagine that you would wrap the state and the data and then expose it to the UI, I would handle the state/data in the ViewModel and notify the UI through differents LiveData (SingleLiveEvent). In addiction your solution presume that the UI is get updated on rotation since you should expose the LiveData returned from the Repository. I would update the UI once, that's why I'm using SingleLiveEvent.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the official guideline is to combine multiple livedatas in the ViewModel using a [transformation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Transformations.html). However usually I prefer to use livedatas only in the communication between the ViewModel and the View, in the repositories I use RxJava or coroutines. So in your example I'd modify the `login` method in the repository to return a `Single` instead of a livedata and subscribe to it in the ViewModel. You can then cancel the subscription when the ViewModel is destroyed. You can find an example of this architecture in this [repository](https://github.com/fabioCollini/ArchitectureComponentsDemo).